# Printing 1-N with N threads. The threads should print it iteratively M times

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency, goroutine

I was having a hard time trying to figure out an algorithm to print the following pattern in go using N goroutines,

```
1, 2 ..... N 
2, 4 .....2N
3, 6 ..... 3N
M*1, M*2 ..... M*N
```

Please help me out.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You say you want to print 1-N iteratively M times, but your output seems to go up to N*M. What should each goroutine do?

Comment: Please post your attempted solution

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to build a linked list of go routines here, passing message from one go routine to another for printing their own dedicated number.

The following code does this (https://play.golang.org/p/Bx6dDne4GFs)

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

var curLevel int = 1
var M int = 1
var N int = 0

var yield chan bool

func main() {
    N = 5
    
    yield = make(chan bool)

    firstCh := make(chan bool) 
    nextCh := firstCh
    for i := N; i > 1; i-- {
        chSelf := make(chan bool)
        go passOver(i, chSelf, nextCh)
        nextCh = chSelf
    }
    
    go passOver(1, firstCh, nextCh)
    
    firstCh <- true
    
    <-yield
}

func passOver(nodeId int, selfCh chan bool, nextCh chan bool) {
    for {
        if curLevel > M {
            close(yield)
        }
        select {
            case <- yield: return
            case <- selfCh:
                fmt.Printf("%d", nodeId * curLevel)
                if curLevel <= M {
                    if nodeId == N {
                        fmt.Printf("\n")
                    } else {
                        fmt.Printf(", ")
                    }
                }
                if nodeId == N {
                    curLevel = curLevel + 1
                }
                nextCh <- true
        }
    }
}
```

I have used here to close all the goroutines safely.

Thing to note here would be that when we close a channel, all listeners on that channel get notified about this.

Other than that it's just a simple circular single linked list.

To understand more of these idioms, I would recommend you to go through the following video. It's an hour of video but it's worth it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6kdp27TYZs